# Clang produces slower code when AVX is enabled?

Tags: xcode, clang, sse, vectorization, avx

I use Xcode 4.5.2 with "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1" (Clang).

I tried to compile a code which heavily relies on SSE intrinsics with AVX enabled (no _mm256* functions and no __m256 variables yet) and got slower code then I get when only SSE 4.2 is enabled.

Is there any reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: If you use any SSE library functions switching between VEC encoded SSE (as in AVX) and legacy SSE without using a `vzeroupper` may cause major stalls. Other than that it should be faster, becuase of the VEC encoded three operand instructions. I experienced a 10% gain in pure 128 bit code by recompiling for AVX.

Comment: Thanks. How can I check if there are such switching functions in the code (maybe they come from a third party library that I use)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently LLVM has opened bugs related to AVX performance, [such as this one](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10928) for example.

The full avx-related bugs list can be found [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=avx).